# input component does not work in tailwind elements

Tags: html, tailwind-css, tailwind-elements

I'm new to Tailwind Elements, I try to use a select element in Vistual studio code, but the borders are not visible.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqjD4.png)

In the js file eh initialized what is indicated:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfO8C.png)

```
import { Select, initTE } from "tw-elements";
initTE({ Select });
```

But it gives me this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D91hK.png)

I reference the js file like this:

```
<script type="module" src="./Main.js"> </script>
```

I don't know what I could be doing wrong, Help me please!! :(

I tried the tutorials on the official site but it didn't work, I hope you can help me solve the error.

Comment: doesn't the error say that it should be `/`, `./` or `../` in front of `tw-elements` ?